# Boostrap Sliser convert into wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types

I create a custom post type slider. I add the title, content and featured image, but there is a button option in my boostrap slider. I dont know how can i add button in the custom post type and how can i display in my site.

Here my slider code:

```
<div class="home-slides owl-carousel owl-theme">
<?php
    $slider = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' =>'slider',
    ));
?>
<?php while( $slider->have_posts() ) :  $slider->the_post(); ?>

<?php $backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>

<div class="main-slider-item" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $backgroundImg[0]; ?>); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
        <div class="d-table">
            <div class="d-table-cell">
                <div class="container">
                    
                    <div class="main-slider-content">
                       <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                           <?php the_content(); ?>
                        
                        <div class="slider-btn">
                            <a href="services.html" class="default-btn">
                                Our IT Services
                            </a>
                            <a href="contact.html" class="default-btn-two">
                                Contact us
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Please solve my issue

Comment: What do you mean 'button option'? Your example is using the *-btn styles - is that what you mean? So your problem is how to get your custom post type view - which is just like a normal post? - to return HTML with a default-btn style?

Comment: I want to make the button dynamic. Means user can change the text and add link of button thorugh admin side under slider post. My slider title, slider image and slider content is dynamatically. But the content of slider button is static. I didnot know how can i make this dynamic.